# "no environment variables set" when not using Matrix on Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

We're cutting in support for testing [ARM64 on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-cpu-architectures). We also stopped using the standard Matrix and switched to exclusively using `include:` to reduce unneeded jobs. Avoiding `matrix:` and using `include:` saves 25 to 50 unneeded jobs.

The result of testing of the change is available [here](https://travis-ci.org/noloader/cryptopp/builds/600299291). About 8 jobs fail in the configuration with the error *"no environment variables set"*:

[image]

We think the jobs are coming from `osx_image: xcode10.1` in `.travis.yml`. It appears the unwanted jobs are the result of `osx_image` applied to `{Linux,OS X} x {GCC,Clang} x {amd64,arm64}`.

We don't know how to stop the jobs or how to work around them.

How do we fix the jobs with *"no environment variables set"* failures?

---

Here is the relevant pieces of `.travis.yml`.

```
language: cpp

arch:
  - amd64
  - arm64

os:
  - linux
  - osx

osx_image:
  - xcode10.1

dist: xenial
sudo: required

git:
  depth: 5

compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc

env:
  global:
    - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk"
    - ANDROID_SDK="$HOME/android-sdk"
    - ANDROID_NDK="$HOME/android-ndk"

jobs:
  include:
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (all)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=all
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (native)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=native
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (no-asm)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (debug)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (asan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (ubsan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (pem)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (autotools)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (cmake)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (all)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=all
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (native)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=native
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (no-asm)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (debug)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (asan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (ubsan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (pem)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (autotools)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (cmake)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (all)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=all
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (native)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=native
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (no-asm)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (debug)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (asan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (ubsan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (pem)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (autotools)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
    - os: osx
      name: OS X with Clang (cmake)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (all)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=all
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (native)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=native
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (no-asm)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (debug)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (asan)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (ubsan)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (pem)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (autotools)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (cmake)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (all)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=all
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (native)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=native
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (no-asm)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (debug)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (asan)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (ubsan)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (pem)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (autotools)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with Clang (cmake)
      arch: arm64
      compiler: clang
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
    - os: linux
      name: Android on Linux (armeabi-v7a)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=android
        - PLATFORM=armeabi-v7a
    - os: linux
      name: Android on Linux (aarch64)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=android
        - PLATFORM=aarch64
    - os: linux
      name: Android on Linux (x86)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=android
        - PLATFORM=x86
    - os: linux
      name: Android on Linux (x86_64)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=android
        - PLATFORM=x86_64
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (iPhoneOS)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=iPhoneOS
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (Arm64)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=Arm64
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (WatchOS)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=WatchOS
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (AppleTVOS)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=AppleTVOS
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (iPhoneSimulator)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (WatchSimulator)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=WatchSimulator
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (AppleTVSimulator)
      arch: amd64
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=AppleTVSimulator

  allow_failures:
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (WatchOS)
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=WatchOS
    - os: osx
      name: iOS on OS X (iPhoneSimulator)
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=osx
        - BUILD_MODE=ios
        - PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator

before_install:
  - |
    ...

script:
  - |
    ...

branches:
  ...

notifications:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> We think the jobs are coming from osx_image: xcode10.1 in .travis.yml

This was incorrect. We removed the global key `osx_image` but the problem still exited.

But we still don't quite understand where the jobs were coming from other than it was a byproduct of `matrix:` expansion, which we were trying to avoid.

---

> How do we fix the jobs with "no environment variables set" failures?

The fix was to get rid of `matrix:` expansion, but it is not readily available information. It certainly was not stated in the docs. Or we could not find it in the docs.

To avoid `matrix:` expansion get rid of all global keys for `env`, `arch`, `os`, `compiler`. The insight is, the global keys trigger the matrix expansion. Matrix expansion ***does not*** depend on the presence of the `matrix:` or `jobs:` keys.

[Our resulting yml file looks like the following](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/.travis.yml). We have to manually build the cross product of `{env} x {arch} x {os} x {compiler}` (which we were already doing).

```yml
language: cpp
dist: xenial
sudo: required

git:
  depth: 5

jobs:
  include:
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (all)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=all
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (native)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=native
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (no-asm)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=no-asm
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (debug)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=debug
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (asan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=asan
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (ubsan)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=ubsan
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (pem)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=pem
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (autotools)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=autotools
        - BUILD_JOBS=2
    - os: linux
      name: Linux with GCC (cmake)
      arch: amd64
      compiler: gcc
      env:
        - BUILD_OS=linux
        - BUILD_MODE=cmake
        - BUILD_JOBS=2

    ...
```

`jobs:` is an alias for `matrix:`, so using `jobs.include` instead of `matrix.include` does not have the intended effect. Also see the [Travis YML Schema](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-yml/blob/master/schema.json).